# Tableau: How to perform "Summarize totals except top 3"?

Tags: tableau-api

I have data something like below for the name of person and the total sales he/she made:

```
ABC1    34
ABC2    45
ABC3    78
ABC4    79
ABC5    23
ABC6    61
ABC7    34
ABC8    54
ABC9    90
```

I have to display the dashboard as below, top 3 sales guys and the overall total sales made by rest of the team as ROT which is 498 - (90 + 78 + 79) = 251 team:

```
ABC9    90
ABC4    79
ABC3    78

ROT    251
```

For the top sales made, I gave a filter by sales person name, with Limit condition as "Top 3". But I am struggling to display the ROI even in a separate worksheet. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click on your dimension `[Sales Guy]` and choose Create/Set
2. Define the set by the Top N (either hard code it or use a parameter to change it easily) and call it `[TopNSalesGuy]`
3. Create a calculated field `[TopNSalesGuysPlusOther]` with the formular:
   `IF [TopNSalesGuy] THEN [Sales Guy] ELSE 'ROT' END`
4. Use `[TopNSalesGuysPlusOther]` in your table/graph and you should have the top N sales guys by name and everythign else as 'ROT

Comment: Thank you so much Alexander. Simple and powerful solution. There were actually 10K + records and multiple fields to display. Just with the Create/Set the report looked awesome.